# How to make HTML table rows have the same size in Haml

Tags: html, css, ruby, haml, css-tables

I have an HTML table created using Haml, and I loop through the values and display them. Each table has different widths for each value and I don't understand  why.

Haml:

```
 - if @downtown.properties.present?
    - @downtown.properties.collect do |property|
      .container
        .row.property-panel
          = link_to downtown_property_path(@downtown, property), :action => 'go' do
            %table
              %tr
                %td= property.name
                %td= property.original_construction_year
                %td= property.street_address 
                %td= property.owner_address_state
                %td= property.owner_address_zip
                %td= property.floor_count
```

CSS:

```
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  height: 50px;
}
```

This is an image of what I'm dealing with:

[image]

Comment: If you inspect the table is there any padding or margin being added, or a default width being added by something?

Answer (score 1):

This one was weird. I don't know what it happened in the first place, and so instead of fixing the issue i spent more time trying to find out what was happening instead.

I didn't specify the width of the `%td`, and adding one took care of the problem.

```
td {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new table for each property, hence the weird spacing. You're not working with one table with fire rows. But with five tables with one row.

Move the table definition out of the loop to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should create one table and add more rows to it instead of creating new tables and fixing the width for table data.

```
- if @downtown.properties.present?
  %table
    - @downtown.properties.collect do |property|
      .container
        .row.property-panel
          = link_to downtown_property_path(@downtown, property), :action => 'go' do
            %tr
              %td= property.name
              %td= property.original_construction_year
              %td= property.street_address 
              %td= property.owner_address_state
              %td= property.owner_address_zip
              %td= property.floor_count
```